# dependency browser that runs against an inversion of control framework

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

Do any inversion of control / dependency injection framworks support viewing the object dependencies that have been registered?  This is not to execute the code, but to better understand it.  It seems that a graph based on the information it has (class A depends on B and C, class B dependencs on C and E, etc) would really document a system well.

I'm using Castle Windsor at the moment, but wouldn't mind trying a different framework for this functionality.

Comment: Question added to the Windsor FAQ: http://using.castleproject.org/display/IoC/FAQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's a little console application](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2008/03/how-to-output-windsor-container.html) that'll output the dependency graph of a Windsor container. Text-only, but still very useful.

I [recently blogged](http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2009/10/visualizing-windsor-components.html) about showing all component dependencies as a proper graph. Sample output (scaled down):

[image: windsor dependencies]

Comment: Well my next question is "what API did they use?", so this is perfect.

Answer (score 3):

For Spring the [Spring IDE](http://springide.org/) shows you a dependency graph.

[image: Spring IDE bean graph]

---

For Guice you can use [Grapher](http://code.google.com/docreader/#p=google-guice&s=google-guice&t=Grapher).

[image: Guice graph]